# Does Hibernate Support Oracle Nested tables?

Tags: hibernate, nested

Just wondering if there is a support for Nested tables in Hibernate ORM implementation. How good it is to use for Huge Data retrievals. Pros and Cons of it in using the Spring + Ajax based web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible but you would have to create your own Hibernate UserType since nested tables are not standard SQL and therefore not directly supported by Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks TheStijn. Do you see any limitations like enforcing integrity constraints and unnesteing is trouble in case we need make some table independent one rather being part of some composite type? Also I wonder even Tom is not in favour of these nested tables..http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8135488196597#tom2714667100346568810

Comment: I haven't worked with nested tables in Hibernate yet but if possible I would avoid it. For the simple reason that nested tables are not standard SQL so you would not be able to switch to another RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks TheStijn for your time.